# email is already registered using jsp?

Tags: java, mysql, database, jsp, servlets

I'm having a problem while making a program in jsp to check into database that email is registered or not.

So i just thought that i could make it using `select * from..` but now this time i'm struggling with redirection.

Actually my program is working fine but there is some few problems with it. I want to make it a way if email is not existed, it should suppose to pint welcome. But nothing is happening. It appears `Blank white page`. Can you  please help me please. Where i'm suppose to be wrong now?

Here is my code:

```
String user_email=request.getParameter("user_email");

try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/forum", "root", "1234");
    PreparedStatement st=con.prepareStatement("select * from login_system where email=?");
    st.setString(1, user_email);
    ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){

            if(user_email.equals(rs.getString("email"))){
                out.print("Email is already registered!!");
            }
            else{
                out.print("Welcome..");
            }
        }
}
catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
%>
```

***Surely, Help would be appreciated!!***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the email is in the database, your query will return exactly one row, if the email is not registered, it will return no rows.

Your code contains two problems: If no rows are returned, `rs.next()` is `false`, so you never enter the while loop.

If a row is returned, there is no need to check the email address, since you only selected mathcing rows.

The code should look like this:

```
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery();
if (rs.next()){
   // we found a row wth the email address
   out.print("Email is already registered!!");
}
else{
  // email not found in database
  out.print("Welcome..");
}
```